# Vorpal.js parameters and arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, vorpal.js

I'm developing a Node.js app and I'm using [Vorpal](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) commands. I'm trying to send a value from the command to a function but i can't get it to work. Am I doing anything wrong?

Here is the code:

```
vorpal
  .command('rollto <num>', 'Rolls to')
  .action(function(num) {
    rollto(num);
  }); 

function rollto(num) {
    bettime = bettimems % 60;
    socket.emit('betting', bettime);
    timer1 = setInterval(function () {
        bettime--;
        socket.emit('betting', bettime);

        if (bettime == 0) {
            socket.emit('random number', num);     
            console.log("Rolled to:" + num + "!!!");
            clearInterval(timer1);
        }
    }, 1000); 
}
```

Comment: What is the current result of executing this?

Comment: @Jared the console.log outputs Rolled to: [object Object] !!!

Comment: We need to see what num is, try this:  console.log("Rolled to:" + JSON.stringify(num) + "!!!");  Whats the output?

Comment: @Jared the solution is below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the function you pass to command's `action` has different arguments than you assume.

Here is the relevant part from [docs](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/wiki/api-%7C-vorpal.command#commandactionfunction):

```
.command.action(function)

This is the action execution function of a given command. 
It passes in an arguments object and callback.

Actions are executed async and must either call the passed 
callback upon completion or return a Promise.
```

And here is a working example:

```
var vorpal = require('vorpal')();

vorpal
.command('rollto <num>', 'Rolls to')
.action(function(arguments, callback) {
    rollto(arguments, callback);
});

function rollto(arguments, callback) {
    var num = arguments.num;  // get 'num' parameter from arguments
    timer1 = setInterval(function () {
        console.log('test');
        console.log(num);
        clearInterval(timer1);
        callback();  // Don't forget to use callback() to notify vorpal
    }, 1000);
}

vorpal
  .delimiter('myapp$')
  .show();
```

Note that you actually have an async code inside setInterval, so you need to use callback() at the end to notify vorpal that processing is finished.

Comment: wow I can't believe I didn't notice something like this, well happens to everyone... It's working now.. I'm off to get some sleep I've been working for 18 hours straight. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: @HugoPires I am glad that it helped :)